# sort() in Python using cmp

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, cmp

I am trying to sort a list, move all 0 to the end of list.
example: [0,1,0,2,3,0,4]->[1,2,3,4,0,0,0]

and I see someone code it in 1 line

```
list.sort(cmp=lambda a,b:-1 if b==0 else 0)
```

But I don't understand what inside the parentheses mean.

Could anyone tell me?  Thank you.

Comment: How much do you understand, how much don't you understand? Do you know what the `cmp` parameter does? Do you know what a `lambda` is? Do you know what the inline `if..else` is?

Comment: try googling your tags: `python`, `lambda`, `sort` and you 'll find how to use them and what they do.

Comment: Even if you know Python, you might miss the fact that this line depends on an *implementation detail* about the order in which the items are compared, so I do think that the question is on topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Preface:

[Sort a list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) according to the normal [comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

```
some_list.sort()
```

Supply a [custom comparator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter):

```
some_list.sort(cmp=my_comparator)
```

A [lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/890128/416224):

```
x = lambda a, b: a - b
# is roughly the same as
def x(a, b):
    return a - b
```

An [if-else-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/416224):

```
value = truthy_case if condition else otherwise
# is roughly the same as
if condition:
    value = truthy_case
else:
    value = otherwise
```

#### The line `list.sort(cmp=lambda a,b:-1 if b==0 else 0)` itself:

Now, the condition in the comparator is whether `b==0`, if so indicate that `b` has a bigger value than `a` (the sign of the result is negative), otherwise indicate that the values compare the same (the sign is zero).

Whilst Python's `list.sort()` is [stable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915376/416224), **this code is not sane**, because the comparator needs to test `a`, too, not only `b`. A proper implementation would use the `key` argument:

```
some_list.sort(key=lambda a: 0 if a == 0 else -1)
```

#### Fixed `list.sort(cmp=...)` implementation:

If you want to use `list.sort(cmp=...)` (you don't) or if you are just curious, this is a sane implementation:

```
some_list.sort(cmp=lambda a, b: 0 if a == b else
                               +1 if a == 0 else
                               -1 if b == 0 else 0)
```

[But notice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20202418/416224):

> In Py3.0, the `cmp` parameter was removed entirely (as part of a larger effort to simplify and unify the language, eliminating the conflict between rich comparisons and the `__cmp__` methods).

#### An alternative:

Sorting a list is in `O( log )`. I do not know if for this simple problem the code runs faster, but I wouldn't think so. An `O()` solution is filtering:

```
new_list = [x for x in some_list if x != 0]
new_list.extend([0] * (len(some_list) - len(new_list)))
```

The difference will probably only matter for quite long lists, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x:str(x) if x == 0 else x)
[1, 3, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0]
```

Guess what's happening here? I am exploiting the fact that, as a preference, python will pick up integers first, then strings. SO I converted 0 into '0'.

Here's the proof.

```
>>> ll = [3,2,3, '1', '3', '0']
>>> sorted(ll)
[2, 3, 3, '0', '1', '3']
```

Answer (score -1):

You should answer yourself and this is plan for make actions for study:

---

The ternary expression description is available here:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary%20operator#conditional-expressions

You can find a lot of expression description in that document:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

---

Q: What does lambda mean?

Please spend just 5 days and read a Tutorial about Python language, which is a fork of the original Gvinno Van Rossum book.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions