# list.sort with lambda acception 2 parameters

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I am upgrading to python 3.5.2 from python 2.6, And i have changed to python 3.5.2 and fixed almost all of the changes. now i am facing an issue while sorting a list.

My previous code is as follows :

```
somelist_variable = [{"idx" : 9, "name": "Syed"}, {"idx": 2, "name": "Mex"}]
somelist_variable.sort(lambda a, b: int(a.get("idx")) - int(b.get("idx")))
```

this above code works fine in python 2.6 , however it is giving an error python 3.5.2, i have checked alot of places to pass 2 parameters to the lambda but i couldnt find anything. Can anyone of you guys help me out with it.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202418/why-is-the-cmp-parameter-removed-from-sort-sorted-in-python3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, can U explain what u want? If U just want to sort somelist_variable by "idx" keyword argument u should write:

```
somelist_variable.sort(key=lambda a: int(a.get("idx")))
```

or advanced

```
from operator import itemgetter
somelist_variable.sort(key=itemgetter('idx'))
```

Comment: sorry, if u sure that idx key is always integer, u can use sort without int() function

Answer (score 0):

This should works in your case

```
somelist_variable = sorted(somelist_variable, key = lambda x: x.get("idx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should only take one argument. The smaller the return value, the earlier in the list the element will be placed:

```
somelist_variable.sort(key=lambda a: int(a.get("idx")))
```

Also, you have to explicitly specify that the argument to `list.sort` is a key.