# TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function

Tags: python, list, lambda, key

This seems to be a syntax error.

Here is the calling function which should be correct.

```
t.sort(key=lambda b: b.length // 2)
```

Here is the function

```
def sort(self, key=None):
    p=self.boxes
    p.sort(key)
    return
```

p is a list inside a class. I am not sure how to get this to sort correctly.

Comment: what do you think that error message means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, you should pass `key` using the keyword argument:

```
def sort(self, key=None):
    self.boxes.sort(key=key)
```

(note that `p` and `return` are unnecessary)

Comment: Why is this?  I haven't seen any other functions that require keywords like this.

Comment: For keyword-only arguments in general, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#keyword-only-parameter). As for [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) specifically, my understanding is that `key` was made kw-only to prevent accidental confusion with `cmp` - an older argument that was removed for Python 3. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20202452/6445069). This illustrates the main benefit of kw-only args - they force the caller to make explicit which arg they mean to pass, which helps both readability and forward compatibility.