# Comparing two values

Tags: python, testing, compare

Say I have two variables:

```
foo1 = 2
foo2 = x # Actual value unknown
```

`foo1` will always be the same (`2`) but `foo2` can take any integer value from `x`.

Now say I want to compare `foo1` to `foo2` (find out if it is smaller, bigger or the same size).  I could use `==` to test if they are the same value:

```
foo1 == foo2 # False
```

So `foo1` does not equal `foo2`.

Next I see if `foo1` is larger with `>`:

```
foo1 > foo2 # False
```

So we now know that `foo1` is smaller than `foo2`.

This can be put into a convenient function to compare values:

```
def cmp(arg1, arg2):

    if arg1 == arg2:
        return 0
    elif arg1 > arg2:
        return 1
    elif arg1 < arg2:
        return -1


print(cmp(2, 3))
```

Where:

- `0` means the same size
- `1` means greater than
- `-1` means smaller than

---

Interestingly Perl has this inbuilt, [the `<=>` (compareson) operator](http://www.perltutorial.org/perl-operators):

```
my $foo1 = 2;
my $foo2 = $x;

$foo1 <=> $foo2;
```

> `1` if `$foo1` is greater than `$foo2`
>
> `0` if `$foo1` and `$foo2` are equal
>
> `-1` if `$foo1` is lower than `$foo2`

This does the same as the Python function I inplamented above.

<sup>Please note that I am not really a Perl coder, but have included this to show that other languages have a compareson feature.</sup>

---

Creating a function is all very well and works fine, however is there some (similar to what Perl uses) inbuilt function/operator that would compare these two values for me (rather than needing to build it myself)?

Comment: Python 2 has [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp). We got rid of it in python 3 for very [good reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20202496/4819449)

Comment: FYI several other languages, such as PHP, Ruby and C++20, have this ["spaceship operator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison).

Comment: Python 3 docs have [an entire article on this subject](http://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html) which you might find useful

Comment: I honestly can't see why you'd want `cmp` over explicit comparison operators though. Surely you'll need to test the result of `cmp` to do anything useful with it anyway. If it's absolutely neccessary, use `cmp = lambda x, y: (x > y) - (x < y)`

Comment: @FHTMitchell  Minimising code mainly. Why 4 lines when I could use 1 ;) That lambda function does exactly as I need and is short enough.  Thank you

Comment: @a625993  Thank you, that article is extremely useful.  I have almost finished reading it.

Comment: A) That's such a perl thing to say. Minimising code is not the most important thing here. The comparison operators are more efficient and more readable. B) It doesn't even do that. I genuinely can't think of a situation where that would be the case. Could you maybe provide one?

Comment: @FHTMitchell  So your advice is to compare them individually.  Fair enough.

Comment: @FHTMitchell  Not really got a specific problem in mind.  It's more curiosity that brought me here

Comment: @Simon fair enough :)